# Button Loading react-hooks-nextjs

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un botón de hilandero de carga(loading spinner), cuando oprimo el botón aparece el icono de carga pero no desaparece al tiempo marcado, y sigue con la carga. Aquí les dejo el código:

***Componente Loader:***

```
import React from 'react'

function Loader(){

    return(
        <>
        <div className="loaderIcon"></div>
        <style jsx>
        {`
        .loaderIcon{
            border: 10px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border-top: 10px solid #3498bd;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes spin{
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
            100% { transform rotate(360deg);}
        }
        `}
        </style>
        </>
    )
}

export default Loader;
```

***Componente LoadingButton:***

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import Loader from '../components/loader'


function ButtonLoading(){

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    function loadData(){
        setLoading ({loading: false})

        setTimeout(()=>{
            setLoading({loading: true});
        }, 1000);

    }
    return(
        <>
        <div>
        <button className="btnLoading" onClick={loadData} disabled={loading}>
        {loading &&(<Loader/>)}
        {loading && <span className="oneSpan">Cargando pagina</span>}
        {!loading && <span className="twoSpan">Cargar Datos</span>}
        </button>
        </div>

        <style jsx>
        {`
        .btnLoading{
            background-color: green;
        }
        .oneSpan{
            color: red;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .twoSpan{
            color: black;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        `}
        </style> 
        </>
    )
}

export default ButtonLoading;
```

Comment: Hola :D no he probado netamente tu codigo ni estoy muy familiarizado con los Hooks pero no deberia ser: setLoading(false) en lugar de pasarle un objeto? { loading: false } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable que devuelve el hook **loading** debe contener un valor bool, no un objeto

Una vez aclarado eso, deberías cambiar

cambiar ***setLoading({loading: true});*** por ***setLoading(true);***

cambiar ***setLoading({loading: false});*** por ***setLoading(false);***